# ASP.NET MVC with multiple user tables and roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an application that uses a client table, a company user table and an admin user table to manage companies. Companies have an admin area where they manage their users with roles of what their users can do, and a level above that the admin manages users that have their roles for managing all companies.

The question is: I want to use asp.net identity with authorize and roles in the appropriate controllers. Is there a way to integrate the existing user tables and roles for all three levels of users?

Comment: You can do everything... but you have to adapt it.

Comment: @Legends, any references on how to do that?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)
You have to get into it, takes same time if you are new to Identity.
So the link above is a starting point, how you will accomplish this depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a referrence table with many to many relationship to the asp.net users table like the below:
1- ASP.NET Users (The one Identity provider will give you)
2- Custom Table called (CompanyUsers) that takes the company ID and User ID 
3- all tables linked to the above custom table